# Sort JPA relational entity lists

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, openjpa

I'm using PrimeFaces to display information in a DataTable. The data in the datatable is actually a List of entity objects which is generated by OpenJPA. And the entities have relations to other entities. This means that there are Lists inside Lists.

For example, an entity called **Authors**, which has many **Books**. The data `List<Authors>` is listed in the datatable. And in order to sort the List i use Collections.sort() which of course doesn't work when i try to sort on the Authors book title. Because the title field is an instance of the Book class.

How do i go about to sort the Lists when there are relationships like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyWithOrderBySetting.htm) tutorial, which use @OrderBy annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of sorting by books title, you need to sort your books list :

```
 public static void main(String args[])   {
            List<Author> list = new ArrayList<Author>();

            for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                Author a = new Author();
                a.setName("author"+i);
                List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    Random r = new Random();
    char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                Book  b = new Book();
                b.setTitle(c+"title");
                books.add(b);
                }

                a.setBooks(books);
                list.add(a);
            }

/*
         * At this point of time you have Authors list which you want to sort by book title.
         * So you can do something like below if you want to do it through Collections.sort
         */

for(Author a : list){
              Collections.sort(a.getBooks(), new Comparator<Book>(){

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
                return  o1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getTitle());

                    }});

          }
            System.out.println(list);


        }
```

Author and Book used in above example:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Author {
private List<Book> books;
private String name;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Author [books=" + books + ", name=" + name + "]";
}
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}
public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**Book.java:**

```
public class Book {
private String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book [title=" + title + "]";
}
}
```